# How can I skip headers in Kohana 3 and just get raw output from a route?

Tags: php, pdf, kohana, kohana-3, dompdf

I have a method that returns a PDF file using [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). It sends all the right headers. It is generated on the fly (not stored on the server anywhere).

I now have to attach this PDF to outgoing emails. I did this in [Kohana 3](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/)

```
        $routeUrl = Route::get('secure_view_pdf')->uri(array('id' => $id));

        $response = Request::factory($routeUrl)->execute();


        $tempFile = DOCROOT . 'tmp/pdf-' . $id . '.pdf';

        file_put_contents($tempFile, $response); 


        $swift = email::connect();
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();


        $message->setSubject('My Subject')
              ->setFrom(array('info@example.com.au' => 'Example'))
              ->setTo(array($clientEmail => html::chars($clientName)))
              ->setBody($body) 
              ->addPart($body, 'text/html') 
              ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($tempFile));

        $swift->send($message);
```

The route it is requesting simply sends the headers to download and streams the PDF so the end user can download it. It also uses the [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) library.

Except when I run this request in the browser, it prompts me to download the file. I want to get the output in `$response` and ignore the download headers `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file #1.pdf"`.

Is it possible to receive this request *as-is* and then save it to a file like I've described above.

Or should I change the auto generation of PDFs to file, and then simply point to that file with Swift?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $response = Request::factory($routeUrl)->execute()->response;
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that. And I think it should work normally, except the DOMPDF extension is sending headers itself. I'll accept anyway as this is the usual way to do this thing.